# Validation on onCellChange with Slickgrid

Tags: slickgrid

I have just started to use slickgrid (++ to the author btw) - running into a few small issues - I want to dynamically update some fields using the in-context editing.  Once editing is done I wish to send this to the server which also should validate what was sent.  If there is an error I would like to handle the error in a similar way to how the validatr event works? e.g. highlight the cell and not let the user to move away until it is valid, however I do not see how I can do so? any advice on this would be much appreciated!

Code so far...

```
grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e, args) {
    var item = args.item;
    var column = args.cell;       
    var row = args.row;
    var value = data[args.row][grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field];
    var id = args.item.id;
    var field = grid.getColumns()[args.cell].field;
    var dataString = "id="+id+"&field="+field+"&value="+value;
    var status = false;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/en/<?php echo $this->controller; ?>/updateattribute/&callback=?'",
        data: dataString,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(a) {  
            console.log(data);              
            if(a.status == true) {                  
                status = true;
            } else {
                status = false;             
            }       
            return false; 
        }
    });    
    if(!status) {
        return false;
    }             
    grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
    data.push(item);
    grid.updateRowCount();
    grid.render();
});
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ajax requests are, by default, asynchronous, which means that

```
if(!status) {
    return false;
}             
grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
data.push(item);
grid.updateRowCount();
grid.render();
```

will probably be executed before the `success` callback. A couple different solutions:

- Make the ajax request synchronous (**not recommended**):

  ```
  $.ajax({ ... async: false, ...})
  ```
- Put all of the code that follows the ajax request in the `success` or `complete` callback.  Something like this (not tested):

  ```
  grid.onCellChange.subscribe(function(e, args) {
      // snip...

      $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "/en/<?php echo $this->controller; ?>/updateattribute/&callback=?'",
          data: dataString,
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(a) {  
              console.log(data);              
              if(a.status) {                  
                  grid.invalidateRow(data.length);
                  data.push(item);
                  grid.updateRowCount();
                  grid.render();
              }
          }
      });
  });
  ```

jQuery's [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) can also provide a clean way to write this.

Comment: Thanks for the response,

Thanks for point about async, have modified as you mentioned.

Ideally though, when status is false then it would respond in the similar way that the validator's work (e.g. flashes the cell in question and does not let you close it down until you have entered a valid input) does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, that does make sense. I'm not all that familiar with SlickGrid to know how to implement that, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend one of two options:

- Submit your change to the server for validation.  Display a spinner to visually indicate that a background process is running and temporarily disable editing and cell navigation while the validation is going on.  When you've received the response, re-enable the editing and navigation or switch the cell back into edit mode and display a validation error.
- Same as above, but keep the navigation going, just disable the editing.  Add an onBeforeCellEdit event handler to display a gentle message to the user informing them that a cell cannot be edited because the server hasn't responded yet and cancel the edit.